# (Objective C) setFont is not working for me

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

In my app, I got a button for user to toggle the font style (either System Font, or Bradley Hand) for certain labels. I managed to save/load the variable by using NSUserDefaults.

On the storyboard, the labels are having BradleyHand by default (along with wChR/wChC/wRhC size class variations).

I have my viewWillAppear method as follows:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger useScriptFont = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"useScriptFont"];
    if(useScriptFont == 0){ //0: switch to system font instead of bradley
        NSLog(@"Font changed");
        CGFloat fontSize = myLabel.font.pointSize;
        [myLabel setFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"No font change");
    }
}
```

When I run the app, it did get into the IF condition, but the font style did not change.

What did I do wrong? Please advice.

Comment: maybe missing [super viewWillAppear:animated] has something to do with this issue

Answer (score -3, accepted):

it might be usefull

```
if(useScriptFont == 0){ //0: switch to system font instead of bradley
    NSLog(@"Font changed");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CGFloat fontSize = myLabel.font.pointSize;
        [myLabel setFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]];
    });
}
```

Comment: i know it's on main thread but if we took label on storyboard then it take storyboard font

Comment: @chirag bhalara Thz It works now, but may I know why? Newbie here :(